# New solution module in outlook 2010 which shows a new form region

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I want to add a new solution module to outlook which acts as a web browser.
I have created a new solution module and a new form region which displays a website. But how to connect those two.

That means when I click the new solution module the new form region has to visible while the others invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

We can create a solution module as explained in msdn. Then we can create a folder link to a web url inside that solution module..

If someone needs the codes I'll give.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a web view for the solutions folder.

```
Sub SetupFolderHomePage()  
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder  
 Dim mpfNew As Outlook.Folder 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set mpfInbox = nsp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
 Set mpfNew = mpfInbox.Folders.Add("MyFolderHomePage")  
 mpfNew.WebViewURL = "http://www.microsoft.com"  
 mpfNew.WebViewOn = True  
End Sub
```

Be aware, you need to add the NonDefaultStoreScript key to the window registry to get the solution working. You can read more about this in the [You cannot add a URL to the Address box on the Home Page tab in Outlook 2007](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/923933?wa=wsignin1.0) article.